# How can I ask questions randomly to different user in django?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-quiz

I want to create a list of questions and from it I want to ask random 5 questions 
to each logged in user.How can i do it. where can I create a list of quetions 
and options.How can I render questions and answer to html page ?

I tried to create a db table and used it to get values in html template
But it did not work.

```
class Quetions(models.Model):
    quetion =models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    option1=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    option2=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    option3=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    option4 =models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
```

Comment: The django tutorial walks you through how to build a poll application.  This is basically what you are looking for.  I suggest doing the tutorial then if/when you have a problem with the randomization, come back with your question. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

While fetching the question, you can do something like

```
pks = Quetions.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
random_idx = random.sample(range(0, len(pks)-1), 5)
random_questions = Quetions.objects.filter(pk__in=random_idx)
```

Comment: how can i store ans to database